# How to add users events in google calendar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

I am integrating Google Calendar into my application. It is integrated successfully, now I would like to add the users event to Google Calendar. If I add users event in Google Calendar the event should be reflected in jSon response.

I am having a problem getting users event in json response.

```
-(void)updateCalendar    
{    
    //NSString *calendarId = @"XXXX-fr62agepgso9n50s9nhv7c2g27inhqg6.apps.googleusercontent.com";        
    NSString *calendarId =  @"47ou48fasc70l0758i9lh76sr8@group.calendar.google.com";        
    NSString *apiKey = @"XXX";        
    NSString *urlFormat = @"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%@/events?key=%@&fields=items(id,start,summary,status)";        
    NSString *calendarUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlFormat, calendarId, apiKey];        
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];        
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];        
    [manager GET:calendarUrl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
    {            
    [ADManagedObjectContext updateEvents:responseObject[@"items"]];            
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];            
    }

    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {                 
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];                 
    }];    
}
```

Comment: @Dalm To help me if you have any idea plz. help me any body

Comment: Have you tried following https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios yet?

Comment: @luc thanks for your response. i followed this tutorial..https://github.com/theandrewdavis/ios-google-calendar.. but i want to add event in google calendar.. next the related added event should be reflected in my json response

Comment: Here is the create event guide: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#add_an_event There is no objective C code but I'm sure you can accommodate according to one of the other languages.

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve all calendars from your device. Then stored all calendars in NSArray by using this code,

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init]; 
caleandarsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

Then add your Events to selected calendar by using this code,

```
EKCalendar *calendar = [caleandarsArray objectAtIndex:1];
[events setCalendar:calendar];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:events span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

By using the above code we can add the event to desire calendar.

**OR**

Instead of using Google API's you should use the EventKit(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/index.html), it is easy stuff and you are able to sync to the Calendar where the user wants.

**OR**

Check this link: http://www.macworld.com/article/2895043/hands-on-with-google-calendar-for-iphone-an-awesome-calendar-for-gmail-addicts.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. but i am using google calendar API.. so using google calendar API how to post event.. i don't want EKEvent kit bro..

Comment: @Abinandan Pratap will  you help me plz

Comment: no bro. actually i need to integrate Google calendar only this is my project requirement